# How to get all the data in a dataframe corresposnding to every nth value of a variable in r?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a vector that contains the time frames, where one frame = 1/60 of a second:

```
x <- 0:120
```

This vector is part of a dataframe which has other variables, e.g.:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 0:120, 
speed = seq(41, 48, length.out = 121), 
position = seq(25.56, 270.23, length.out=121))
```

I want to get the values of all the variables  when 1 second is completed every time. So, for `x` that means `60` and `120`. In the `df`:

```
data.frame(x = c(60,120),
speed = c(44.50000, 48.00000), 
position = c(147.89500, 270.23000))
```

How can I get these values using `dplyr`? I have tried different variations of `dplyr::lag` and `dplyr::lead` but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to accomplish what you want is to filter to only rows where x divided by 60 has no remainder:

```
df %>% filter(x / 60 == round(x / 60))
```

If you also want to remove the first row where x equals 0:

```
df %>% filter(x / 60 == round(x / 60) & x != 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works, if you don't mind including the row where x=0:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 0:120, speed = seq(41, 48, length.out = 121), 
                 position = seq(25.56, 270.23, length.out=121))

df %>%
  filter(x %% 60 == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to be repeatable for an undisclosed number of variable in these intervals, then setting the equation above by markus to:

```
df[df$x%%60==0, ]
```

will do the trick. What this says is to subset df where df$x is evenly divisible (%% is modulo meaning no remainder) by 60.

If you wanted to do this with dplyr you would do the following:

```
filter(df, x%%60==0)
```

If you have a zero row this will still show up, so you will need to say `& x!=0` to remove those 0 rows.